# How can I do an AES encryption using a password and a salt in such a way that I can decrypt using only that same password and salt in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

How can I do an AES encryption using a password and a salt in such a way that I can decrypt using only that same password and salt in Java. I need this because I want to encrypt my data before putting them in the database and I do not want to store any IV byte array in the database for decryption. I just want to encrypt the data using a password and a salt store the encrypted data in the database so that when I need the data, I get it from the database and decrypt it using the same password and salt, nothing more.

Comment: You can use an all-zero IV each time for encryption and decryption - it won't be as secure as if you used a unique IV, but whatever floats your boat

Answer (score 1):

**AES** is a block cipher that encrypts in blocks of 16 bytes. If you encrypt the same 16 bytes of data with the same key (or password + salt), you will end up with the same encrypted data. This have some undesirable (insecure) properties that the **initialization vector** is used to solves.

If you don't want to keep track of an **initialization vector**, you can instead make **the first 16 bytes of your data be random**, and then use an initialization vector set to 16 zero's. This will give the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities:

1. Use AES-CTR.  Counter mode does not require an IV.
2. Derive both your key and IV from your password and salt.  Something like:

   key <- hash(password + salt + "KEY")

   IV <- hash(password + salt + "IV")

Obviously in real life you would use a standard key derivation function, depending on how much security you need.

You might also wish to think about authentication to check that what comes back from the database is the same as what you put there.  For built-in authentication use AES-GCM instead of AES-CTR or else add an HMAC if you are using the second option.

Comment: Please can you show me how to use the AES-GCM or AES-CTR using a sample code, I am new in cryptography

Comment: Counter mode without initialization vector (or blank vector) is really bad, as xor of two encrypted messages = Xor of the plain text. This is because counter mode work by encrypting the iv+counter and then xor with the plain text.

Comment: The unique record ID from the database would serve as a nonce for CTR mode.